# После шифрования невозможно декодировать файлы

Tags: python, шифрование, encoder

Пишу программу, которая реализует алгоритм шифрования CS-Cipher. Работаю с 16ричным представлениям битов.
Если использовать стандартную кодировку(utf-8), то при выполнении

```
key = None
    text = 'test value'
    startText = text.encode().hex()
    while len(startText) % 16 != 0:
        text = text + ' '
        startText = text.encode('').hex()
    cs = CSCipher(startText, False, key)
    encrypted = cs.encrypt()
    print(cs.subkeys)
    cs1 = CSCipher(encrypted, True, key)
    decrypted = cs.decrypt()
    print(startText)
    print(bytes.fromhex(encrypted).decode(''))
    print(bytes.fromhex(decrypted).decode(''))
```

появляется ошибка
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte`
либо
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Если установить кодировку 'utf-16', то ошибка появляется через раз
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: illegal UTF-16 surrogate`
или
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x28 in position 22: truncated data`

utf-32 не работает от слова совсем.

Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы у меня не вылетала программа? Или зашифрованный текст всегда придется представлять в виде строки 16ричных данных, а не текстом.

Comment: Зашифрованный текст это далеко не всегда печатаемые символы. Вряд-ли вы можете декодировать его в обычный текст

Comment: Вы в своём коде никак не используете переменную cs1, для начала исправьте это